# Search Option in Textbox

Tags: extjs4

I am using ExtJs4.I have a form in my web application in which there is text box.The scenario is to provide an AJAX like search(like Google) when any key is pressed in the text box.Search will look into a web service and display the result(JSON object) in drop drown.Similar to Google search.

Is there any idea,link or tutorial for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **ComboBox** for this. With trigger or without one (that looks like a **TextBox**).

Sencha provides good examples:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/combos.html
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/forum-search.html

This is a simple example:

```
{
        xtype: 'combo',
        id: 'myCombo',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
                model: Ext.define('ComboModel', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                        fields: ['id','data1','data2']
                }),
                proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url : 'data.json',
                        reader: {
                                type: 'array'
                        }
                }

        }),
        triggerAction: 'query',
        minChars: 2,
        fieldLabel: 'Search',
        displayField: 'data1',
        msgTarget: 'side',
        triggerCls : 'x-form-search-trigger', // Search Icon For Instance
        listConfig: {
                getInnerTpl: function() {
                        return '<div>{data1}</div><div>{data2}</div>';
                }
        }
}
```

And **JSON** file:

```
[
    ['1','data1-1','data2-1'],
    ['2','data1-2','data2-2'],
    ['3','data1-3','data2-3'],
    ['4','data1-4','data2-4'],
    ['5','data1-5','data2-5']
]
```

Comment: Hi Natasha,Thanks for ur suggestion,Here i need to send id field from json as an input value of combobox.How to set?

Comment: Please make another question. The answer doesn't fit the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/forum-search.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this example http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/forum-search.html will be interesting for you. This realization use standard combobox control. In your case you need to set minChars property = 1, in this case store binded to Combobox will generate standard READ query with filter param to server. You can generate results there.